# How to remove an array element from an array by length

Tags: php, arrays

My array output is this. I want to get 'ATM/Cash Withdrawals' from this array. In my array elements how I remove array element length is 1?

```
var_dump($array)


null
null
string 'ssf3'
null
string '2' (length=1)
null
string '2' (length=1)
string 'ATM/Cash Withdrawals' (length=20)
null
null
null
null
null
```

Comment: Kindly post your `array()` with `<pre>` wrapped.

Comment: Have you try `array_filter()`?

Comment: [**Check This**](https://3v4l.org/eGmZD)

Answer (score 1):

Try `array_filter`

```
$output = array_filter($array, function($k) {
return strlen($k) != 1;
});

var_dump($output);
```

Read [Array Filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: You're almost there.. add the `strlen` function as the answer above.. avoid getting down votes

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($i) {
  return strlen($i) != 1;
});

var_dump($filtered);
```